# Pandas numpy.where() use - Not getting the desired result

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to merge two columns into a third column based on the NaN values

```
df['code2'] = np.where(df['code']==np.nan, df['code'], df['code1'])
```

I am getting only the values if code1 column in the code2. The result is coming as shown in the image
Output image

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong in the code i am writing. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for comparing `NaN`:

```
df['code2'] = np.where(df['code'].isnull(), df['code'], df['code1'])
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

> **Warning**
>
> One has to be mindful that in python (and numpy), the nan's don’t compare equal, but None's do. Note that Pandas/numpy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.

```
In [11]: None == None
Out[11]: True

In [12]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[12]: False
```

> So as compared to above, a scalar equality comparison versus a None/np.nan doesn’t provide useful information.

```
In [13]: df2['one'] == np.nan
Out[13]: 
a    False
b    False
c    False
d    False
e    False
f    False
g    False
h    False
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to check if a value is nan is to use `np.isnan(val)`:

```
np.nan == np.nan
False

np.isnan(np.nan)
True
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 1, 2]})

>>> np.isnan(df.a)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```